# How to change background Image sizing

Tags: css, wordpress

My URL: http://www.dreambelle.com/
[image]
The background image (white main, grey side bar) that is behind the text and sidebar below the slider is placed too low. You can see this issue to the right of the slider behind the side bar content...

The problem is that I cant figure out how to move the background image up via css without moving the entire body content up?
[image]
The background image is rendered from a small bar (attached)

Comment: What is your CSS look like for the background image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do both (make the #featured_body with a smaller height), and adjust the margin on the #sidebar

Ive tested the following this works for me in FF5:

```
// Remove 10px from the #featured_body height
#featured_body {
    background: url("images/bgr_board.png") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    float: left;
    height: 356px;
    margin: 0 12px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 618px;
}

// Add 10px to the sidebar top margin
#sidebar {
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    margin: -375px 0 20px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 332px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your `div#content`, which has the `background-image` is placed below your `div#featured_body`, which is pushing it down.

You have two choices, as I see it:

1. make the `div#featured_body` smaller height-wise, so that the bg image lines up with the `twitter div` or
2. place anther `wrapper div` around all the content under the `nav` and add the `background-image` to that. (That is, if you wanted the bg-img to stretch to the top of the page).